# Check class_exists before class definition / Doxygen problem

Tags: php, oop, customization, documentation

Currently when I create a class for my WordPress, I start the class with

```
if ( ! class_exist( 'class_i_want_create' ) ) :
    .... 
    class_definition
    ....
endif;
```

But now I want to create a documentation with Doxygen. But Doxygen doesn't find the class when it's surrounded with the `class_exist`.

So is it a bad practice when I don't surround it with the `class_exist`?
Or does anybody know how I can configure Doxygen to see the class even when it's surrounded with the `class_exist`?

Comment: Is the class you're creating *likely* to be defined already?

Comment: I think not, because I start all my classes with a small prefix. But as I started to develop a wordpress plugin, I learned that it's good practice to use the class_exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like doxygen has some problems with such code, but... There are some solutions...

You can use [INPUT_FILTER](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter)s for that. After doxygen docs:

> The INPUT_FILTER tag can be used to specify a program that doxygen
>   should invoke to filter for each input file. Doxygen will invoke the
>   filter program by executing (via popen()) the command:

So you can use this script as a filter (as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26206860/217040):

```
<?php
    $source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
    $regexp = '#(<\?php[\s]+)(if\(!class_exists\([^\)]+\)\)\{)([\s\S]*)(\})([\s]*\?>)#';
    $replace = '$1 $3 $5';
    $source = preg_replace($regexp, $replace, $source);
    echo $source;
?>
```

Or another one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655189/217040):

```
// input
$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);

// removes the whole line
list($head,$tail) = preg_split('/.*if\(!class_exists\(.+/', $source, 2);   

$openingBracePos = strpos($tail,'{');
$closingBracePos = strrpos($tail,'}');

if($openingBracePos !== false && $closingBracePos !== false)
    $source = $head . substr($tail,$openingBracePos+1,
                             $closingBracePos-$openingBracePos-1);

echo $source;
```

Comment: Thanks! The filter doesn't work for my code (currently I don't know why) but now I know what I can do to solve my problem :-). I will post my filter when I'm getting it to work.

Comment: Now it works.
I had to adjust the regex source code as follows:
$pregsplitarray = preg_split('/.*if\s\(\s!\sclass_exists\(.+/', $source, 2);